# Cakephp phpunit.xml blacklist gets ignored while testing

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

When I run my tests on cakephp 2.6 the `/plugin` folder tests get included. I tried to set the blacklist option in the `phpunit.xml` and the test uses the file, but the plugins will still be included.

The command I am using and the following text from the command promt

```
$ Console/cake test app All --stderr --configuration phpunit.xml

Welcome to CakePHP v2.6.13 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : site
Path: /var/www/MYPAGE/site/
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/MYPAGE/phpunit.xml
```

My `phpunit.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="2048M" />
    </php>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./plugins</directory>
            <directory suffix=".ctp">./plugins</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./vendor</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

As you can see I would like to ignore tests from the `vendor` and `plugin` folder next to the app/src folder.

I also tried without the configuration option

`$ Console/cake test App all --stderr`

The plugins that gets automatically called are:

/plugins
--Authenticate
--Crud
--DebugKit
--..
/src

Answer (score 0):

The `<filter>` section is solely ment to filter files/locations from code coverage analysis.

If you were to narrow down what is being tested in a PHPUnit configuration file, then you'd need to configure `<testsuites>` accordingly. However, as you know, in CakePHP 2.x you do not run PHPUnit directly, but use the CakePHP test shell, and that requires to programmatically create test suites - which seem to exist in your setup, otherwise passing `all` should result in an error (at least that's the case in the latest 2.x).

Taken from the docs, a test suite that would only test your apps tests could look like this:

```
// app/Test/Case/AllModelTest.php

class AllTestsTest extends CakeTestSuite {
    public static function suite() {
        $suite = new CakeTestSuite('All tests');
        $suite->addTestDirectoryRecursive(TESTS . 'Case');
        return $suite;
    }
}
```

and you'd run it like:

```
Console/cake test app AllTests
```

See also

- **[PHPUnit Manual > 3.7 > Code Coverage Analysis > Including and Excluding Files](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/phpunit-book.html#code-coverage-analysis.including-excluding-file)**
- **[Cookbook > Development > Testing > Creating Test Suites](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#creating-test-suites)**

Comment: Thank you. I am using a test suite named ` AllTest ` that I can call with ` $ Console/cake test app All --stderr ` and here I don't include any plugins.
My plugins, the ones I would test are based within the app/src folder.
But the ones that get automatically tested are the one in the root directory ./plugin

Comment: @ChrissPony Sorry, I cannot reproduce that, the example shown here and in the docs, do work as expected for me.